# HTML5 Doctype with iframe

Tags: css, html, iframe

When including a full height/width iframe within an HTML5 doctype, there is a border added to the bottom which I cannot seem to remove. This adds a scrollbar to the page to account for the border. Unfortunately, I am restricted by the following:

- Need to use an iframe
- iframe is inside a container that is fixed position taking up the entire screen
- html and body have overflow hidden
- Need the HTML5 doctype (removing the doctype or switching to an older doctype will fix the scrollbar issue)
- Need to keep overflow-y: auto and -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch on the #container as iOS does not scroll the frame otherwise (or can't seem to make it scroll).

I have a plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/uqAYy6Hl9hwrtzRtKdqX?p=preview) that exhibits the same. Removing the html5 doctype from this shows it would fix the issue (but that is not a viable solution).

Is there any CSS or attributes that would remove that border bottom and remove the outer (unnecessary) scrollbar?

```css
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#container {
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

#foo {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <iframe id="foo" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"
      src="//www.iana.org/domains/reserved"></iframe>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please review and test my solution on an iPhone. I'm curious whether it succeeds, but not so curious to buy an iPhone. :P

Comment: I didn't bother testing since there were two scrollbars present when viewing in desktop browser.

Comment: Updated http://plnkr.co/edit/QkF05lhU3dH3qhn7JQ7N?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "bottom border" is not a border, it is an inline element space (an iframe is an inline element), so the fix is to get rid of that "space".

Here are 3 ways for "foo":

- `display: block`
- `position: absolute`
- `margin-bottom: -4px;`

Note: `display: block` appears to not work so well in some cases on iOS.

```css
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#container {
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

#foo {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <iframe id="foo" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"
      src="//www.iana.org/domains/reserved"></iframe>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I was excited for this solution... For some reason, this breaks scrolling on the iphone as well :(

Comment: Does it break using `margin-bottom: -4px` as well ? ... Check my update.

Comment: I'm scared about the magic number 4px. Is there something in any spec that says thats what margin inline elements get around it? I did try setting position: absolute on #foo and that seems to work on initial testing (really would have preferred block though).

Comment: The negative margin is well know to fix the space between inline elements which as well cause this. You can read more here about that "space issue": https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Let me know how it works with iPhones (what worked best and what you choosed) and I add that as a note to my answer.

Comment: Ideally display block would have worked, but scrolling was broke. Initial attempts on one iOS device show that position: absolute is working. I also considered doing something similar with height: calc(100% - 4px) on #foo, but the hard-coded 4 seemed to be a hack (even though initial testing seems to show 4 is the right value to use across current browsers). I'm accepting this answer as I was fixated that it was a border rather than some spacing because of inline element.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that by default, for elements that are not using `display: block` that there is an extra margin.

The following CSS-only solution appears to work on both Mobile Safari and Chrome desktop.

```css
.demo-iframe-holder {
  position: fixed; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.demo-iframe-holder iframe {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>

  <body>
    
    <div class="demo-iframe-holder">
        <iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" src="//www.iana.org/domains/reserved"></iframe>
    </div>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: That does get rid of the scrollbar in desktop, but does not allow you to scroll in iphone for instance (edit and open the plunker in iOS, turn landscape, and see scrolling does not work)

Comment: I've modified the answer to work with Mobile Safari and tested it on my iPhone 6. It appears to be working as you intended.

Comment: Chrome on desktop (and other desktop browsers) have dual scrollbars with this due to overflow-y: auto... Nothing is different in your updated answer than in my original post... To clarify, my post currently works on iphone -- looking to get it to work on desktop browsers without breaking scrolling on phone.

Comment: I've modified my answer to provide a solution. Perhaps it's not the most elegant because it uses JavaScript but it appears to work.

Comment: Rewarding your time with upvote -- Looking for CSS only solution and I think we are close with LGSon.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I came late to the party... my solution is **untested** on any mobile device. All changes are annotated on the CSS (`style.css`) and there's only one modification to the markup: `scrolling="no"` to `iframe#foo`.

[**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/QkF05lhU3dH3qhn7JQ7N?p=preview)

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <iframe id="foo" frameborder="0" scrolling='no' marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"
      src="//www.iana.org/domains/reserved"></iframe>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
/* S.O. 33571717 */
/*=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=*/

/* NOTE: This style is contingent upon the iframe #foo... */
/* having the attribute: scrolling="no" */

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html,
body {
  /* If html is 100%... what is html's parent? 100% of nothing? */
  /* Having +100% unit higher than max will extend overflow: auto */

  /* Using vh and vw units to ensure accurate viewport dimensions... */
  /* see http://goo.gl/yQZX8v */

  height: calc(100vh + 100%);
  /* set as vh instead of % */
  width: 100vw;
  /* set as vw instead of % */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* split overflow's axis */
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#container {
  /* changed from fixed */
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  /* split overflow's axis */
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

#foo {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  /* added #foo to 'flow' of #container */
  position: absolute;
  /* #foo is stretched to every corner of #container */
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  /* split overflow's axis */
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

/* THIS HAS NOT BEEN TESTED ON ANY MOBILE DEVICES */

/* This media query is DEVICE specific to an iPhone 6+ */

/* NOTE: Use media queries for landscape and portrait mode... */
/* the properties are reversed basically */

/* iPhones do not follow a simple logic for media query dimensions... */
/* see http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/ */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-width: 736px) and (orientation : landscape){
  html, body {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: auto;
    height: 100vh;
    width: calc(100vw + 100%);
  }
  #container {
    overflow-x: auto;
  }
  #foo {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: auto;
  }
}
```